# How to add inline toolbar for contenteditable="true" content?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I'm working on a page that can edit it's content in the page.

I'm using contenteditable="true" for all the contents inside the page.

When the user clicks a section to edit I want to display an inline toolbar that has some basic options. (Something like: https://builder.dynamicxx.com/templates/93218/newview)

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="home">
  <form action="action.php" method="post">
    <div class="heading">
      <h1 contenteditable="true">Page Heading</h1>
      <input type="hidden" class="clone-heading">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p contenteditable="true">Page content</p>
      <input type="hidden" class="clone-content">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I'm using a form with hidden input fields to save the content the user adds.

Is there a way to display an inline toolbar when the user clicks on the content?

Comment: Not simply and easily. To do this is outside the scope of StackOverflow, there may be a jQuery plugin that will help you out

Comment: Can you recommend any jQuery plugins that can help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make a toolbar with the absolute position on the left side hidden, when someone clicks on the content you can remove hide and apply show on it.

Comment: I'm familiar with that. But I'm looking for a plugin or anything from where I can get the toolbar.